# is there DefinitelyTyped for mongoose-unique-validator in TypeScript

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, definitelytyped

Just like the title says, I lookup the TSD Site, can't find any DefinitelyTyped for mongoose-unique-validator.

So I want to know is there solution for use mongoose-unique-validator without DefinitelyTyped in TypeScript. provide some demo could be better, 
thanks for watching this question and help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your own type information for it if you like but how to do that is a big question. If you just want to use it without having type information for it, the simplest way is to use the ES5-style require

```
var uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');
```

If you use var instead of import it doesn't complain about your lack of type information.

Comment: thanks a lot. can you answer my first question, I add some details for my issue.

Comment: This is a terrible solution, if you want to ignore it then use `// @ts-ignore` explicitly. The answer here should encourage the community to contribute to Definitely Typed or show how to stub the `.d.ts` file as a stop gap.

Comment: @hally9k This answer was written in the dark days of early 2016 TypeScript version 1.X. `@ts-ignore` did not exist until over a year later and at the time definitely typed had more than a few missing entries. Please feel free to contribute updates to the answer to bring it up to the modern day. If you happen to find yourself writing 1.X typescript, this is a fine approach.

Comment: @Paarth Good call I totally overlooked the date in my haste. I maintain that circumventing the type system in this way is not the preferred solution, even in TS 1.x. A stubbed `.d.ts` file would be preferable, no? Unless they didn't exist in those days either? 

Comment: @hally9k If you're talking about [shorthand ambient modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#shorthand-ambient-modules) those weren't there yet. `.d.ts files` in general were, but there were already answers and tutorials covering how to write them. I interpreted the OP's question as how to progress *without* them given their disinclination toward tsd which was the dominant way of working with typings at the time and essentially a package manager in its own right. The cost of entry was high,the demand for TS was higher, and people were very confused on where to begin.

Comment: I mention that for historical context. Please do feel free to edit my answer with the changes you'd like to see.